# RecyclerView not displaying any data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my Application I m having a `RecyclerView` in one of my Fragments in which I am getting response from a server using `Reterofit`. Every thing is fine but My `RecylerView` is not displaying any data returned from my service. Even the

```
int count = offerRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();
```

of my adapter is returning the correct amount of data count returned from server.

**Inside Fragment:**

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        offersRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer_recycler);

        MotorCityArabiaGlobal global = (MotorCityArabiaGlobal) getActivity().getApplication();
        ApiInterface apiService=global.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<OfferResponse> call = apiService.getOffers(4);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<OfferResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OfferResponse> call, Response<OfferResponse> response) {
                OfferResponse offers = response.body();
                if(offers!=null){

                    List<Offer> result = response.body().getResult();
                    offerRecyclerAdapter = new OffersAdapter(getActivity(),result);

                    offersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    offersRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    offersRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                    offersRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                        }
                    });

                    int count = offerRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();


                    offerRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<OfferResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class OffersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OffersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Offer> offersList= Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context ctx;

    public OffersAdapter(Context ctx,List<Offer> offersList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.offersList = offersList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
//                .inflate(R.layout.offer_list_layout, parent, false);
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_list_layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Offer offer = offersList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(offer.getOffer_title());
        holder.price.setText(offer.getPrice());
        holder.offerCount.setText(offer.getOffer_count());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return offersList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, offerCount, price;
        public ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            offerCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer_count);
            price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.car_img);
        }
    }
}
```

**home_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/header_wrapper"
    >
    <!-- Row1-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >
        <!-- Column1 row 1-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/new_car_selector"
                android:clickable="true"

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                ></LinearLayout>

        <!-- Column2 row 1-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/find_car_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            ></LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Row2-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"

        >
        <!-- Column1 row 2-->


        <!-- Column2 row 2-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sell_car_selector"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            ></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/compare_car_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            ></LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    <!-- Header Wrapper ends-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_wrapper"
        android:id="@+id/offers_recycler_wrapper"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CAR OFFERS"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccentDark"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/offer_recycler"
            ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**offer_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sell_car_select"
        android:id="@+id/car_img"

        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/meta_data"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/car_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/title"

            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:text="13,000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccentDark"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/curr"
                android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
                android:text=" SAUDI RAYAL"
                android:textSize="12dp"

                />


        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/offer_count_wrapper"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="12dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_offer_orange"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text=" 3 Offers"
        android:id="@+id/offer_count"
        />
</LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try changing your RecyclerView `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`

Comment: @Budius it didnt work

Comment: you put A LOT of code, so it was a suggestion to what seemed more obvious to me. But @SepJapRo2.4 answer seems right to me. You forgot to add the adapter to the Recycler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set the adapter to the `RecyclerView`. Use `setAdapter` method. See the following code,

```
List<Offer> results = new ArrayList<Offer>();

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    offersRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer_recycler);
    offersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    offersRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    offersRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    offerRecyclerAdapter = new OffersAdapter(getActivity(), results)
    offersRecyclerView.setAdapter(offerRecyclerAdapter);

    offersRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });


    MotorCityArabiaGlobal global = (MotorCityArabiaGlobal) getActivity().getApplication();
    ApiInterface apiService=global.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<OfferResponse> call = apiService.getOffers(4);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<OfferResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OfferResponse> call, Response<OfferResponse> response) {
            OfferResponse offers = response.body();
            if(offers != null){

                List<Offer> result = response.body().getResult();
                results.clear();
                results.addAll(result);
                offerRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OfferResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: uh I forgot to get attach the adapter. thanks its working now.

Answer (score 2):

add the line below in your **onResponse** after **offersRecyclerView.addItemDecoration();**

```
offersRecyclerView.setAdapter(offerRecyclerAdapter);
```

hope this helps.